# insert - not recorded field in the table

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
INSERT INTO `jos1_content` 
  (`title`, `introtext`, `fulltext`, `state`, `sectionid`, `catid`, `attribs`)
VALUES  
  ($title, $introtext, $fulltext, 1, 1, $catid, 5)
```

Query is made up of php script. Derivation of variables shows that they are not empty.
At the request of phpMyAdmin shows the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Comment: Are you trying to insert HTML into the database? If so you need to escape it first using mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Are you feeding this string to phpMyAdmin ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to indicate strings to SQL - use:

```
INSERT INTO `jos1_content` 
  (`title`, `introtext`, `fulltext`, `state`, `sectionid`, `catid`, `attribs`)
VALUES  
  ('". $title ."', '". $introtext ."', '". $fulltext ."', 1, 1, $catid, 5)
```

A safer means would be to use:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `jos1_content` 
                    (`title`, `introtext`, `fulltext`, `state`, `sectionid`, `catid`, `attribs`)
                  VALUES  
                   ('%s', '%s', '%s', 1, 1, %d, 5)",
        mysql_real_escape_string($title),
        mysql_real_escape_string($introtext),
        mysql_real_escape_string($fulltext),
        $catid);
```

Reference:

- [SPRINTF](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)
- [MYSQL_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: You have not added single quotes to his query, you just changed the way the variables are embedded in the PHP string. There are still no single quotes around the variables in the query sent to MySQL, so it will still fail in the same way.

Comment: +1 for mysql_real_escape_string. I also see that the query is corrected after Dan Grossmans comment above.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: There are 2 single quotes before `$title`. I think it should be only 1.

Answer (score 7):

You need to surround your PHP variables that are being inserted into string-type fields with quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `jos1_content` 
(`title`, `introtext`, `fulltext`, `state`, `sectionid`, `catid`, `attribs`)
VALUES  
('$title', '$introtext', '$fulltext', 1, 1, $catid, 5)
```

Comment: Assuming his query is enclosed in double quotes, yes it will, unlike your response

Comment: @Dan Grossman: It has nothing to do with PHP. The quotes are required because SQL requires them.

Comment: Mark, I was replying to OMG Ponies saying that this use of single quotes would not work. That comment was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Read about prepared statements in the manual of your programming language or use `mysql_escape_string`.